# Count printed numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using this formula to show a '1' if a row exists: `=IF(E2<>"","1","")`.

I'm then trying to count the 1's to output how many rows we have..

However if I count the output '1' shown in column F it stays as a 0 e.g. it doesn't seem to see them as a number? I've tried changing the type in Column F to numbers but still no luck.

Any idea how to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=IF(E2<>"",1,"")`

`1` is a number, `"1"` is text.

You could also use arrayformula to prevent having to drag the formula down from cell `F2`.

Put this in cell `F1` and delete everything below in col F:

`=arrayformula({"Count";IF(E2:E<>"",1,"")})`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the end goal simply this:

`=COUNTA(A2:A)`

There is no need for Column F at all. Just place the formula wherever you want the count of rows to go.